# Java 8 Complex Stream filters And vs Or

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a table object that has three columns that I am using to filter events.

The three columns with hypothetical values:

```
Component Event SubEvent
    A       B       C
    A       B       D
```

I am trying to create an event stream that filters out the first row but not the second. I've tried this a couple different ways with mixed results.

```
return events -> save(events.stream().filter(event -> 
                 A != event.getComponent() && 
                 B != event.getEventType() && 
                 C != event.getEventSubType())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

This behaves like an "or" and filters out both rows.
i.e. if component == A || event == B || subEvent == C

What I really want is

IF (component == A && event == B && subEvent == C) then filter out but keep 
everything else.

I've modified my filter to

```
.filter(event -> C != event.getEventSubType())
```

But then I risk missing other events where subEvent == C but the Component and Event value do not match A and B.

Appreciate any other strategy suggestions on best practices to set up this kind of compound filter. Thanks!

Comment: Beware : compare String with equals().

Comment: @davidxxx, this question isn't about string equality, I believe.

Comment: @M. Prokhorov  I didn't write an answer about. But the problem is concerning the filter on String values. So comparing them in the correct way would be a good start.

Comment: why write a brittle code to skip the first line ? Why not use instead `skip(1)` ?

Comment: @davidxxx, We don't actually know if that's true, there are no class definitions for `Event` type attached. It could be enum. He could choose those operators tor the code to look clearer. The one version which was removed in edit certainly looked like there were enums.

Comment: What you're missing here is DeMorgan's Theorems: `!A && !B == !(A || B)` and `!A || !B == !(A && B)`. This is why it behaves like an "or", your `!A && !B && !C` filter is equivalent to `!(A || B || C)`.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, thanks, you are correct, they are actually enums and I just tried to make the code easier to read without that overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `skip(1)` allows to skip the first element of the Stream.

About your issue, your actual filter :

```
filter(event -> 
         A != event.getComponent() && 
         B != event.getEventType() && 
         C != event.getEventSubType())
```

means that are kept in the stream only elements that respect these `three` conditions.

Look at these rows :

```
 Component Event SubEvent
     A       B       C
     A       B       D
```

The condition is false for the first line.  So the element is not kept.
But the condition is also false for the second line as a series of logical AND is true only if all conditions are true and two of them are not true :

```
         A != event.getComponent()   --> false
         B != event.getEventType()   --> false
         C != event.getEventSubType() -->  true
```

So no one of these line are kept.

What you should write is :

```
filter(event -> 
         !(A == event.getComponent() && 
           B == event.getEventType() && 
           C == event.getEventSubType()))
```

Comment: `!(A == event.getComponent() &&  B == event.getEventType() &&  C == event.getEventSubType())` is the same as `A != event.getComponent() ||  B != event.getEventType() ||  C != event.getEventSubType()`

Comment: @Holger  Sure I don't know why but I find the first way more readable.

Answer (score 1):

So why not create filter that exactly matches first, row and then negate it in your stream filter? That way you will reject all events that match first row, like so:

```
Predicate<Event> FIRST_ROW = event-> 
                 Object.equals(A , event.getComponent()) && 
                 Object.equals(B , event.getEventType() && 
                 Object.equals(C , event.getEventSubType();

save(events.stream()
.filter(FIRST_ROW.negate())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as

```
save(events.stream().filter(event -> 
         !("A".equals(event.getComponent()) && 
         "B".equals(event.getEventType()) && 
         "C".equals(event.getEventSubType()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Or equivalently

```
save(events.stream().filter(event -> 
         !"A".equals(event.getComponent()) || 
         !"B".equals(event.getEventType()) ||
         !"C".equals(event.getEventSubType())
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
```